# php+symfony - phpunit test - Cannot instantiate interface error

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, doctrine, phpunit

I'm trying to write my first php unit test. But I get the next error:

> Error: Cannot instantiate interface Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry

What is the reason and how can I fix that? I'm using PHP + Symfony.
Here's a sample of code of a Service Controller, where I use the function add:

```
class OrdersService
{
    protected $ordersRepository;
    protected $manager;
    protected $router;

    public function __construct(OrdersRepository $ordersRepository, EntityManagerInterface $manager, RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->ordersRepository = $ordersRepository;
        $this->manager = $manager;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function add($shoesid, $sizeid) {
        $cart = $this->session->get('cart', []);

        if(!empty($cart[$shoesid][$sizeid])) {
            if(($cart[$shoesid][$sizeid]) < 3){
                $cart[$shoesid][$sizeid]++;
            } else {
                $cart[$shoesid][$sizeid] = 3;
            }
            
        } else {
            $cart[$shoesid][$sizeid] = 1;
        }
        
        $this->session->set('cart', $cart);
    }
}
```

And here's the code of the test:

```
class OrderTest extends TestCase
{
    public function addShoes3()
    {
        $registry = new ManagerRegistry();
        $ordersRepository = new OrdersRepository($registry);
        $router = new RouterInterface();

        $ordersService = new OrdersService($ordersRepository, $manager, $router);
        $actual = $ordersService->add(40002, 400);
        $expected = $ordersService->add(40002, 400);

        $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you are doing exactly what the error is telling you - trying to instantiate an interface. Interfaces are not classes and you can't make objects out of them.

Answer (score 1):

Just as the error message tells you: In your test you try to create an instance of an interface with `new ManagerRegistry()`. But you cannot instantiate interfaces.

In your `OrdersService` you have those services, because you add them as constructor arguments and symfony's dependency injection component handles their creation.

In your unit test you generally don't want to have real instances of all these dependencies (with all their own dependencies etc.). Instead you want a mocked version. A mock that just acts as it were the real object. Therefore you need to create mocks for all dependencies an add them to `OrdersService` in your test:

```
public function addShoes3()
{
    $registry = $this->createMock(ManagerRegistry::class);
    $ordersRepository = $this->createMock(OrdersRepository::class);
    $router = $this->createMock(RouterInterface::class);

    $ordersService = new OrdersService($ordersRepository, $manager, $router);
    $actual = $ordersService->add(40002, 400);
    $expected = $ordersService->add(40002, 400);

    $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, but now when I'm trying: 
$actual = $ordersService->add(40003, 410);
$expected = $ordersService->add(40002, 400);
$this->assertEquals($expected, $actual); 
I get that the test passed successfully (OK - 1 test, 1 assertion). Why this happens?

Comment: @Silentcow thats another problem and should probably be addressed in a separate question. But short answer anyway: your test doesn't really test anything. Your `ordersService->add()` returns null. So any two calls to `add()` return the same.

Answer (score 0):

**WebTestCase** :

Application tests are PHP files that typically live in the tests/Controller/ directory of your application it tell Symfony that we need the tools necessary to talk to our application as if we were doing so via HTTP.

**KernelTest**

use for to fetch a service from the dependency injection container it help you creating and booting the kernel in your tests

that's why I recommend you to use KernelTestCase

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;

class OrderTest extends KernelTestCase
{
private $registry;

protected function setUp(): void
{
   self::bootKernel();
   $this->registry = self::getContainer()->get('Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry');
}

public function addShoes3()
{
     $registry = $this->registry;
    //continue
}
}
```